# Redirect all URLs to the same path except the bare domain name

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want all URLs that are typed to redirect to this path:

```
/directory/index.php
```

except my domain name `www.example.com`. But currently when I type the domain it redirects me to that path too.

Here is my `.htaccess` code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#prevent mod_dir from adding slash
DirectorySlash Off

# rewrite everything to index file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /directory/index.php [L]
```

If I type my domain name it will redirect to that path as well, I don't want that.

Comment: What is wrong with your solution you posted? In other words: what do you need help with?

Comment: if i type my domain name it will return to that path as well.

Comment: Well, then implement an exception.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^ /directory/index.php [L]
> ```

To avoid the bare domain being redirected (in `.htaccess`) then simply change the `RewriteRule` *pattern* from `^` to `.` (ie. a single dot). For example:

```
RewriteRule . /directory/index.php [L]
```

The dot matches 1 character. When you request the bare domain then the URL-path that is matched is empty, so it will not match.

There is no need for an additional condition/exception in this instance.